# How to validate Symfony2 sha512 passwords using nodejs

Tags: node.js, symfony, hash, pbkdf2

I need to be able to validate in `node` some password which were generated and stored using `Symfony2` with `sha512` encoding.

I can retrieve the `hash` and the `salt` just fine but when using `crypto` I cannot manage to generate a hash using the salt which matches the one stored in the database.

Symfony security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512
```

Hash stored in DB

```
6zxwRZc4EPXKxQes9avs0ZyCRFkC4dtpXrT983ML8VLvv9WhRnAi282bwuFuj3LHPQBGmqD1BfCLDUXGdHIjZQ==
```

Salt stored in DB

```
qu7rjvaietws8kg4cgsggksookwsws8
```

As there is a salt on the node side I'm using `crypto.pbkdf2Sync`, there is no iterations set in the configuration and it seems like the Symfony default is 1000. The default length however is 40 yet the stored hash length is 128 so using 128 as length (tried 40 without success).

I have also tried 5000 iterations as used by Symfony 2 `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` and merging the raw password with the salt as symfony does `raw_password{salt}` without success.

I can also get a base64 long enough if I use `pbkdf2Sync` to generate a key of length `40` (as per symfony default) and then using that to update a hash generate with `crypto.createHash`

```
var hash = user.password;
var salt = user.salt;

console.log(hash);

console.log(crypto.pbkdf2Sync("password", salt, 1000, 128 >> 1, "sha512").toString("base64"));
```

The size of the hash generated and format matches the one stored in the database but they do not match in values which is my issue. I also tried multiple iteration values dynamically generated without any luck.

Output

```
6zxwRZc4EPXKxQes9avs0ZyCRFkC4dtpXrT983ML8VLvv9WhRnAi282bwuFuj3LHPQBGmqD1BfCLDUXGdHIjZQ==
5QPz3zXwhak/bTD2S9IFEEFmiJ8q/fqIlSF6cWin7dqmh92EFNXjw/FLtQw7NX3LVehwcXKjfypo2EhJxiLouQ==
w9+8xjklvGq9CuiqY8tEoxEetLV9lbhLJ/KaFQEooUFJrGT9/EdsVd/sSRJ+DXjsH4RQeaqsmftmuzLPgVv5MA==
```

How can I generate the hash so it matches the way used by Symfony 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symfony does 5000 iterations with sha512.

1. They concatenate raw password with user's salt to generate a new salt
2. They generate a starting hash with above data.
3. On each iteration previous hash its updated with the current hash + new `salt` generated at step 1.

In node, on each iteration you should digest previous hash as binary and in the end digest as base64, to mimic what Symfony does.

And an example:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var encodePassword = function (raw, salt) {
    var salted = raw + '{'+salt+'}',
        hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(salted, 'utf-8');

    for (var i = 1; i < 5000 ; i++) {
        hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash.digest('binary')+salted);
    }

    return hash.digest('base64');
};

console.log("Password: "+ encodePassword("secret", "h2zaays1cx2og00c6ow2gc0k4skg41g"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello might be it will be useful for someone. 
This is part of code from my live website that works.

https://gist.github.com/konstantinzolotarev/deec71876739f8bf1058

Answer (score 0):

Check [Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.php) source code to see defaults values. Also keep in mind that Symfony will do a base64_encode by default

Comment: Thanks, it Seems like the default is indeed `1000` and already using `base64` encoding too so tried and failed already. The one weird thing is that the default length is 40 yet the stored hash is 128. I tried 40 but the length of the hash wasn't matching the DB one which is why I'm using 128.

Comment: Pretty sure that sha512 maps to the MessageDigestPasswordEncoder and not Pbkdf2PasswordEncoderwhich. I could be wrong.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html