# Validating SHA512 hashes from PHP in node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sha512

I'm trying to port a legacy password hashing scheme from PHP to Javascript (node.js), but I'm missing something in the process.

---

### Original, working PHP version

Here is the "original", working code:

```php
function create_hash($password) {
    $salt = uniqid();
    $algorithm = '6'; // CRYPT_SHA512
    $rounds = '1234';

    // This is the "salt" string we give to crypt().
    $cryptSalt = '$' . $algorithm . '$rounds=' . $rounds . '$' . $salt;

    $hashedPassword = crypt($password, $cryptSalt);

    return $hashedPassword;

}

function hash_is_valid($password, $hash) {
    return (crypt($password, $hash) == $hash);
}
```

Working test with above PHP functions:

```php
echo $password = 'secret';
echo '<br /><br />';

echo $hash = create_hash($password);
echo '<br /><br />';

echo 'Should be true: ';
$valid1 = hash_is_valid($password, $hash);
var_dump($valid1); // outputs "bool(true)"
echo '<br /><br />';

echo 'Should be false: ';
$valid2 = hash_is_valid('wrong_pass', $hash);
var_dump($valid2); // outputs "bool(false)"
echo '<br /><br />';
```

### Javascript Version (broken)

Here's what I've got so far, but it isn't quite there

```js
function hash_is_valid(password, hash, cb) {

    // Hash Format:
    // $[algorithm]$[number_of_rounds]$[salt]$[hashed_password]
    let hashParts = hash.split('$')
    console.log(hashParts)
    let salt = hashParts[3]
    let numRounds = parseInt(hashParts[2].substr(7)) // from string like rounds=1234
    let originalHashResult = hashParts[4]

    let salted = password + '{' + salt + '}'
    let processedHash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(salted, 'utf-8');

    for (let i = 1; i < numRounds ; i++) {
      processedHash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(processedHash.digest('binary') + salted);
    }

    processedHash = processedHash.digest('base64')

    // Capture the result
    let hashVerified = (processedHash === originalHashResult)

    // Call the callback with the result
    cb(hashVerified)

}

hash_is_valid('secret', '$6$rounds=1234$56ab50921c460$P4bgd3kMX2xyWJTDOYAdow.jsXiS2TARUJW4BXifgm4czraOIDFLqZ5Ii50GLIKwYTjWwN6WrtG82omQes0cK0', (passed) => {
  console.log((passed) ? 'password is good' : 'password is no good')
})
```

*javascript based on answer to SO question [How to validate Symfony2 sha512 passwords using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179033/how-to-validate-symfony2-sha512-passwords-using-nodejs)*

The javascript version is using some test values:

password: `secret`

hash: `$6$rounds=1234$56ab50921c460$P4bgd3kMX2xyWJTDOYAdow.jsXiS2TARUJW4BXifgm4czraOIDFLqZ5Ii50GLIKwYTjWwN6WrtG82omQes0cK0`

Comment: Can you show what hash does your js code produce? The problem can be in what extra symbols nodejs base64 implementation uses. Also I've noticed that for-loop runs `numRounds - 1` times since it starts with 1.

Comment: @ksimka — example base64 output of hash looks like:  `nyqekS7RsL62iyBLbCtO9OTKPmNvO1n9mq7yZA15E7x3URU7YN1qsWYjAErujvptidcp1+nYytx4wJGSsAjX0A==`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crypt3` NPM package to accomplish this:

```
var crypt = require('crypt3'),
    password = 'secret',
    hash = '$6$rounds=1234$56abadac833a5$fQIaUG/da/KqlJc5DzCIym/PL.ZhEdw5VOZsw7mofkm.3aE2rZ/rjDCczymRbj1V3rF6lzJO7DR1WOd2ZnC6O.';

function hash_is_valid(password, hash) {
  return hash === crypt(password, hash);
}

console.log(hash_is_valid(password, hash)); // true
```

Both PHP's `crypt` function and NPM's `crypt3` package delegate to [crypt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) so given identical data, should produce the same result.

Comment: Perfect. This is much simpler. Note that it does not work on OS X, but does work on Ubuntu.